# SOQL order results based on picklist value

Tags: soql, picklist

I want to run a query that returns Cases ordered by status: "Escalated" first, "New" second, "Working" third, and "Closed" last. Can that be done without creating a formula field?

By the way my actual use-case involves a custom object.

Comment: Where's the query going to be used?  i.e. Apex code?

Comment: @NickCook Yes in Apex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picklist values are ordered based on their order on the field setup page. So if you have, for example:

- Escalated
- Working
- New
- Closed

Then that will be the order, like if `Escalated` was 1, `Working` was 2... and so on.

[The **documentation** states that](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm):

> The following limitations apply to data types when using ORDER BY:
>
> ...
>
> picklist sorting is defined by the picklist sort determined during setup
>
> ...

So if you want a different order, you might just need to change the order of the values. If that is not an option, then you might need to use a formula, indeed.

Comment: Re-ordering the values is not an option unfortunately. I wanted to see if SOQL has a special way to order picklists -and it seems the answer is no. Thanks.